# simplexml_load_string -- Identical Object Properties

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<item>
    <title>Avoid tornado death by spinning backwards</title>
    <link>www.example.com/survival_tips</link>
    <pubDate>Mon, 13 Aug 2043 00:16:21 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>Helen Hunt</dc:creator>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded></content:encoded>
    <category domain="post_tag" nicename="surv"><![CDATA[Survival]]></category>
    <category domain="category" nicename="tip"><![CDATA[Tips]]></category>
    <category domain="category" nicename="torn"><![CDATA[Tornados]]></category>
</item>
```

Consider the XML above.  I can easily access title with:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $entry) {
     echo $entry->title.", ";
}
```

How can I do that for all the `<category...>` fields?  (I realize I could do this if they were wrapped in a parent `<Categories>` tag, but they're not.

Expected Output: `Survival, Tips, Tornados`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Updated to reflect iteration within "item" loop

```
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $entry) {

    $categories = array();
    foreach ($entry->category as $category) {
        $categories[] = (string) $category;
    }

    echo 'In ', $entry->title, ': ', implode(', ', $categories);
}
```

See [Example #4 Accessing non-unique elements in SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5281)

Comment: thanks @Phil. so if embedded in a `foreach ($feed->channel->item as $entry)` loop, i'd be best practice to just do `$itemIndex++;` ?

Comment: Also handy in these cases `$categories = iterator_to_array($entry->categories, false);` see http://php.net/iterator_to_array - `implode` will cast the `SimpleXMLElements` to strings here for you.

Comment: @hakre Too many times I've been bitten by the *SimpleXMLElement is not a string* thing so now I just cast them whenever I want a string

Comment: @Phil: Yes, I think it's important to learn about the string-context that exist in PHP. I learned about it relatively late my own, that is whenever a function outputs a string or expects it in it's input, plus with constructs like `echo`, the cast to string is done. This is also useful if you implement the [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method on your own objects. It works really well, so it's okay to step into these waters. Casting to string still has it's use, esp. with SimpleXML, just adding a bit to it.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case I would suggest to get the `category` elements as an array via the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath` function<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.xpath):

```
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $entry) {
    echo $entry->title . ", " . implode(', ', $entry->xpath('category'));
}
```

Which gives for your single example item:

```
Avoid tornado death by spinning backwards, Survival, Tips, Tornados
```

And done. ;) See as well [`implode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/implode).